# UINavigationItem - Removed "prompt", but extra space for prompt still appears

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xcode4, uinavigationitem

So, I had a UINavigationItem with a value for the "prompt" property (which shows the smaller text along the top of the bar).

I decided I didn't like the text, so I removed it.

But the extra space remains.

Obviously I can just recreate this view... but I was wondering if anyone has seen this before, and if there is a simple fix (something akin to pressing ctrl-0 in SQL Management Studio to insert a null instead of an empty string).

[image: UINavigationItem with too much space]

Comment: Seems like a bug. I have never experienced this in Interface Builder 3. Oh wait, I never use IB for iPhone development. :p

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.0 Build 4A304a

Comment: @WTP... yeah, I'm getting to that point as well... I always feel like I'm fumbling around trying to do things in IB when I could do them faster in code. Plus, you're pretty severely limited as to what you can do in general through IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I just right-clicked on the .xib, and choose "Open As" > "Source Code"

Then I removed this line:

```
<string key="IBUIPrompt"/>
```

Problem solved.